# Python: How to do something every 'n' iterations but only with the previous 'm' values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deque, collatz, periodic-task

I'm attempting to collect statistics from the Collatz Conjecture. Currently, my script gets the length of the Collatz sequence of every number starting from 2 to a large, preset number and saves that length into an ever-growing array. Every 100 iterations it collects several statistics from the **all** the previous data and saves them to a dictionary like this:

```
    result = []
    data = {}
    for count, v in enumerate(range(2, 10000000), 1):
        if count % 100 == 0:
            result.append(len(collatz_concise(count))-1)
            Max = round(max(result), 2)
            Min = round(min(result), 2)
            Mean = round(sum(result) / len(result))
            Median = round(statistics.median(result))
            Range = round(Max - Min, 2)
            Trim_Mean = round(stats.trim_mean(result, 0.1), 2)
            stat = np.array(result)
            Q1 = round(np.percentile(stat, 25), 2)
            Q3 = round(np.percentile(stat, 75), 2)
            data[count] = [Min, Q1, Median, Mean, Trim_Mean, Q3, Max]
```

I would like for the statistics to be collected every 100 times but **only on the previous 100 values of the list**. I've looked around for a while but couldn't find a suitable answer.

Be gentle, I'm fairly new at this and StackOverflow as well.

Comment: Please indent your sampled code correctly.  Currently the indent doesn't look right after the `if count % 100 ==0:` line.  It's crucial to know what goes into the condition and what doesn't.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Periodic actions

The way to perform an action of every *n* steps is to take the count modulo *n* and check to see if it is zero.

### Tracking recent values

The easiest way to track *m* most recent values is with [*collections.deque()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects) with the *maxlen* parameter set to *m*.

### Overview of approach

Here's some code to get you started:

```
>>> n = 15
>>> m = 20
>>> result = deque(maxlen=m)
>>> for i in range(100):
        c = collatz(i)
        result.append(c)
        if i % n == 0:
            print(i, '-->', result)
```

Here's the output:

```
0 --> deque([0], maxlen=20)
15 --> deque([0, 4, 1, 10, 2, 16, 3, 22, 4, 28, 5, 34, 6, 40, 7, 46], maxlen=20)
30 --> deque([34, 6, 40, 7, 46, 8, 52, 9, 58, 10, 64, 11, 70, 12, 76, 13, 82, 14, 88, 15], maxlen=20)
45 --> deque([13, 82, 14, 88, 15, 94, 16, 100, 17, 106, 18, 112, 19, 118, 20, 124, 21, 130, 22, 136], maxlen=20)
60 --> deque([124, 21, 130, 22, 136, 23, 142, 24, 148, 25, 154, 26, 160, 27, 166, 28, 172, 29, 178, 30], maxlen=20)
75 --> deque([28, 172, 29, 178, 30, 184, 31, 190, 32, 196, 33, 202, 34, 208, 35, 214, 36, 220, 37, 226], maxlen=20)
90 --> deque([214, 36, 220, 37, 226, 38, 232, 39, 238, 40, 244, 41, 250, 42, 256, 43, 262, 44, 268, 45], maxlen=20)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I hadn't even heard of the collections library until now